# Regex all between tag with filter

Tags: regex, expression

```
tag(ALL:newlines,tabs,char,espaces)CAN0022(ALL:newlines, ..)/tag
```

I need select all between `tag(.|\s)*?\tag` but only when containing `string = CAN{\d4}`.

I tried many combinations but failed.

Comment: you should try this `tag(.+CAN\d{4}.+)\/tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been trying to match the closest occurrences of `tag`, you should have tried a [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
tag(?:(?!CAN\d{4}|/?tag)[\s\S])*CAN0022(?:(?!CAN\d{4}|/?tag)[\s\S])*/tag
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mA2jQ7/1)

You need to adjust this regex to your own engine/programming language (like escaping forward slashes). Instead of `[\s\S]` you might perhaps use `.` in singleline/dotall mode. Also, `|/?tag` should be adjusted depending on the real text you need to match.

And a special note on `(.|\s)*?` - do not ever use it. It is sooo inefficient that your regex will crash your app when running into catastrophic backtracking sooner than later. Instead, use a dot `.` in dotall/singleline mode (declare `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern, or use the corresponding flag), or use a `[\s\S]` character class (in JS, it is equivalent to `[^]`).